# Find Laurent series in the deleted neighborhood $0<\vert z \vert<R$.

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I am asked to find the Laurent series for

$$f(z)=\frac{\sin(z^3)}{z^4}.$$

In the deleted nehgborhood $0<\vert z \vert<R.$

So by using the series for $\sin z$ I obtain

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{z^{6n-1}}{(2n+1)!}.$$

So the negative $1$ term is just $1$? And is this the correct result or do I need to reindex still?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: The first term (obtained with $n=0$) is $z^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes, @ChristopheLeuridan which has coefficient $1$, correct?